# How to use stream() in a nested Set (Set<Set<Integer>>)

Tags: java, set, java-stream

So i have a nested Set:

```
Set<Set<Integer>> WinningLines = Set.of(Set.of(0, 1, 2), Set.of(3, 4, 5), Set.of(6, 7, 8), Set.of(9, 10, 11),
                    Set.of(12, 13, 14), Set.of(15, 16, 17),Set.of(18, 19, 20),Set.of(21, 22, 23),
                    Set.of(0, 9, 21), Set.of(3, 10, 18),Set.of(6, 11, 15),Set.of(1, 4, 7),
                    Set.of(16, 19, 22), Set.of(8, 12, 17),Set.of(5, 13, 20),Set.of(2, 14, 23));
```

What i want to do, is to go through each of my subsets with  stream(), check if the subset is containing a specific Integer and output the subset, which is containing the Integer.
My first approach was:

```
WinningLines.stream().forEach( System.out::println);
```

I tried to use `filter(integer -> integer == 1)`, but it didnt work either. Is it possible to access a subset with `stream()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a simple for loop:

```
for (Set<Integer> set: winningLines) {
  if (set.contains(value)) System.out.println(set);
  //and break if you only want to print the first one
}
```

With a stream approach, it could look like:

```
Optional<Set<Integer>> firstSet = winningLines.stream().findFirst(set -> set.contains(value));
```

Or if you want them all:

```
Stream<Set<Integer>> sets = winningLines.stream().filter(set -> set.contains(value));
sets.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: works for me, is it also possible to access the Integers inside Stream<Set<Integer>> sets. So i would like to do further operations with these integers.
And why do i need to use a Stream<set<Integer>> here?

Comment: I'm not sure I undersdand - `sets` is a stream of `Set<Integer>` so you can apply whatever operations you need to that stream instead of just printing the sets.

Comment: ah okay thank you. is it also possible to stream a Set Set in order?
It works fine for a single set but not for a Set Set.

Comment: A Set is not ordered - you can use a `LinkedHashSet` if you care about insertion order or a `TreeSet` for natural order (which does not make sense in your case).

Comment: how can i initialize my Treeset, like i did with my nested set in the original question?

Comment: As mentioned, you probably want a LinkedHashSet, not a TreeSet. [How to create a LinkedHashSet](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+create+linkedhashset+in+java+site:stackoverflow.com&safe=active&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBJE883JE883&sxsrf=ALeKk02WDm9CES9cW3jh-q6_97uaeKyQlQ:1625151576959&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjh-cyzkcLxAhUK6RoKHbNjB0MQrQIoBHoECB8QBQ&biw=1920&bih=975).

Answer (score 1):

Your filter expression is wrong. You need

```
WinningLines.stream().filter (set -> set.contains(1))
                        .forEach( System.out::println);
```

You led yourself astray with the name of your lambda parameter: the variable `integer` is actually of type `java.util.Set`, and comparing it `== 1` will always yield `false`. You need to check if the set contains a `1`.